# SQL Server SUM in subquery causing arithmetic overflow when the SUM is less than a 32-bit int

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have a database that has `Manifest`'s which contain multiple `Inventory` items.  Each inventory item has a integer `NetWeight`.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    (SELECT SUM(NetWeight) FROM Inventory WHERE Inventory.ManifestID = Manifest.ID)
FROM Manifest
```

which is throwing an exception: `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.` and I do not understand why.

Recently, the `Inventory` table *has* exceeded the size of an int if you `SUM(NetWeight)` with no filter.
However, I know and have verified that there are no `Manifest`'s with a value greater than 100,000 for that subquery.
If I append `WHERE ID > 0` to the end of the query, it runs fine.  All `Manifest` IDs are greater than 0, so this is theoretically equivalent to having no filter at all.

I know I can just convert it to a `bigint` and continue with my day, but I want to understand why SQL is overflowing.
Is it internally summing the entire Inventory table for some reason?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

---

Estimated query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJETnFUpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top branch of the execution plan selects all 1,098,300 rows from `Inventory` and performs

```
SELECT SUM(NetWeight), 
       ManifestID
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY ManifestID
```

The output of this (estimated 6 groups) is merge joined onto `Manifest` (with a right outer join meaning that all rows from `Manifest` are preserved).

`Manifest` has a cardinality of 5 rows.

Presumably there exists a `ManifestID` in `Inventory` which is causing this overflow for a group but is unmatched in `Manifest` so is eliminated by the join.

Maybe rows where `ManifestID` is `NULL`?

You could try changing the query to

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    (SELECT SUM(NetWeight) FROM Inventory WHERE Inventory.ManifestID = Manifest.ID AND Inventory.ManifestID IS NOT NULL)
FROM Manifest
```

to get these rows eliminated earlier in the plan ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BbPKuL9w)).

You might also evaluate an index on

```
Inventory(ManifestID) INCLUDE (NetWeight) WHERE (ManifestID IS NOT NULL)
```

to avoid reading these rows entirely and provide a useful covering index for the aggregation by `ManifestID`.

Comment: Interesting.  Yes, ManifestID can be null, and that is the majority of the Inventory.  I didn't realize that the query planner could do something like that, but it does make sense in hindsight.  The NULL check resolves the issue.  Thanks for the detailed explanation.